# How to define a range from -50 to 50 using regular expression

Tags: javascript, angular, regex, typescript

my question is, how to define a regular expression, if a range is between -50 to 50.

I have used this regular expression:

```
'\\b(-?[1-9]|-?[1-4][0-9]|-?50|[0-9])\\b'
```

but it can only check from 0 to 50

Why I use this pattern, because I use this pattern for input field such like this:

```
<inpit [pattern]="regex">
```

this pattern can only accept regex string

any solutions??

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this?  Why not use a simple range comparison in your JavaScript code?

Comment: Match from 0 to 50 and make the - optional `-?\b(?:\d|[1-4]\d|50)\b`

Comment: you could generate your regex pattern in a loop; no need to write it manually

Comment: because I use this pattern for input pattern, which can only use regex. such like this: <input [pattern]="regex">

Comment: Hi Cedric, can u give more information?